# How to Retrieve a Hidden Extension in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

All of a sudden my Chrome extensions are gathered in a hidden menu in Chrome:

[image: extensions hidden]

When I click on the double arrow I see them all.

How can I return them to be visible not in a menu, but on the browser itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right on the edge of the omnibar you can grab it and expand or shrink the size of the extensions area. The edge I am referring to is right to the right of the bookmark star, or in your layout it looks like it would be to the left of the star.

Answer (score -1):

If you hide your extension, you can solve that. On your right hand to the top corner you can see three lines going directly down, if you click on it, not right click but click on it go down until you see "more tools" then it will give you a list of some things, go down until you see "extensions", then click on that, and press show, then you can live your normal life.